# What is the one-time 0.257 tz burn fee?

Tags: smart-contracts, contract, fee

I have deployed a contract on a test net and I want to send some tez to it to test out some operations. When I try to send through Temple wallet, I get:

```
Failed
Unable to estimate transaction to provided Recipient.
This may happen because:
Minimal fee for this transaction is greater than your balance. A large fee may be required because of you sending funds to an empty Manager account. That requires a one-time 0.257 ꜩ burn fee;
Network or other technical issue.
```

What is this 0.257 burn fee and why do I need to do it on a contract? Is it a reveal? How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The burn fee is a payment you make to "initialize" a new address or contract. This prevents mass-spam creation of addresses with no contents/value from clogging up storage.

Comment: I see, so how would I pay that burn fee when I deploy a new contract?

Comment: You simply add that amount to the transaction fee. It will be deducted/burnt automatically by the network. If you are using the tezos-client CLI, just add `--burn-fee 0.257`

Comment: Is it possible to do it through the SmartPy website? I'm able to deploy the contract through there but not through `tezos-client`, even if I add 0.257 to the network fee